# getting list of objects from model in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I m creating a list of object and putting it in my model and sending this model to my jsp.

I want to access these list of objects in javascript

something like

```
var x={data.list};
```

but javascript doesnt allow this instead i have to do

```
var x="{data.list}";
```

which gives string representation of object and not object

I need list object and need to iterate over it and get my objects

Comment: The simplest way is to add a Jackson ObjectMapper to the model and call `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(theList)`

Answer (score 0):

In model set the value of data.list. Where ever you need to access the list, define a property with collections tag. Specify a style id for that tag. Use that style id in java script.

Answer (score 0):

use some key value pair while returning data like

```
var x="{key: data.list}";
```

create a function to loop through items of list

```
function performListOperation(list) {
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            // do something with item
        });
    }
```

and call this function like

```
 performListOperation(x.key)
```